# Database named "postgres"

Tags: postgresql

I've just set up Postgres for use by different users on my network. Every user has his own username/password/database, but when I connect to Pg I can also see a 'postgres' database (and even create tables etc). I tried to REVOKE access to that database from public but then it won't let me connect. What exactly is the postgres database and why is it needed? Can I disable it so that users only see the database(s) I've created for them?

Answer (score 3):

The postgres database is created by default when you run `initdb`.

[Quote from the manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-initdb.html)

> *Creating a database cluster consists of creating the directories in which the database data will live (...) creating the template1 and postgres databases. When you later create a new database, everything in the template1 database is copied. (...) The postgres database is a default database meant for use by users, utilities and third party applications.*

There is nothing special about it, and if you don't need it, you can drop it:

```
drop database postgres;
```

You need to do that as a superuser of course. The only downside of this is that when you run `psql` as the postgres operating system user, you need to explicitly provide a database name to connect to

Answer (score 1):

If you drop the `postgres` database you'll find a few things to be confusing. Most tools default to using it as the default database to connect to, for one thing. Also, anything run under the `postgres` user will by default expect to connect to the `postgres` database.

Rather than dropping it, `REVOKE` the default connect right to it.

```
REVOKE connect ON DATABASE postgres FROM public;
```

The superuser (usually `postgres`), and any users you explicitly grant rights to access the database can still use it as a convenience DB to connect to. But others can't.

To grant connect rights to a user, simply:

```
GRANT connect ON DATABASE postgres TO myuser;
```

Comment: Revoking connect on the the 'postgres' database prevents my users from connecting to their 'regular' databases, e.g. they get "Error connecting to the server: FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres" DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege." Granting those rights to a user allows them to view and edit the database, which is a bit weird considering this is a "system" database and only the superuser is supposed to have access to it (at least in terms of writing/modifying).

Comment: Also, the fact that this is a publicly accessible and writable database means users can "spam" the database with data (up to a very large size) and/or overwrite things other users have written. It's not a big deal really but it is an annoyance and I'd like to know what the best practices are as far as dealing with this special database.

Comment: @user3609832 Re preventing connection to other DBs... No, it shouldn't. You can verify this with `psql`. Maybe they are using a tool that assumes this db is present? If they are using pgadmin they must override the default system database.

Comment: @user3609832 The "best practices" are to revoke access to it as stated. Or you could revoke create on schema public and instead if you insist on having the `postgres` db accessible. I strongly suggest you do some reading on multi-tenant hosting schemes for PostgreSQL.