# postgres createdb could not open relation

Tags: postgresql

Again, please be kind. I'm not a dba and I inherited some old postgress databases.

One of my very ancient debian servers running postgres 7.4.7 filled the data file system. One of my cohorts decided to attempt a reindex followed by a 'vacuum all'. All of this failed miserably and left me with even less space. Now when I run 'psql -h' as postgres I get

> 'psql: FATAL:  could not open relation "pg_trigger": No such file or directory'.

I can use psql to access the database in question. If I 'psql database' I can run `'CREATE DATABASE temp;'` but 'psql temp fails with the above error. I do have what appear to be valid `pg_dumps`. Oh and there's no postgres database like I see on other servers. My question is: Is there a way to solve the above error or failing that is there a way to completely reset the database(s)?

Keep in mind that I can't upgrade postgres (as much as I want to).
Some thing I hope may help:

- The data is in /var/lib/postgres/data/base.
- When I run createdb or dropdb I get the FATAL error.
- It'not my fault but it's now my mess.

Comment: One more thing. I did Google this six way from Sunday. The best I found called for removing files and running initdb. But I have a feeling that may not be the best choice. But what do I know? I'm just the linux admin.

Comment: maybe enterprisedb people have some tool that helps you to recover the db.

Comment: There was a free subscription time ago.

Answer (score 0):

> Oh and there's no postgres database like I see on other servers

That's bad.

It sounds like somebody (not you, presumably) tried to `DROP TABLE pg_somethingorother;`. Since the `pg_` tables (also called the catalog) are where things like table names, trigger code, etc, are kept, that sort of table drop is going to cause many problems.

> Is there a way to solve the above error or failing that is there a way to completely reset the database(s)?

You stated earlier that you had some valid pg_dump files. I recommend the following course of action:

1. Test those dump files. Ideally, that means getting a machine with disk space, and the appropriate postgres version (7.4.7 is ancient, as you note, so this might be hard), issuing `initdb`, and then loading the dump file (if the file has plaintext sql in it, that's something like `psql < dumpfile`; if it's not text, you'll use `pg_load`).
2. If the dump files work, go back to your original machine, delete that broken database directory (`/var/lib/postgres/data` -- the directory with `base` and the conf files in it).
3. Use `initdb` to start from scratch, then load it up, like you did in step 1.
4. Create a cron which issues appropriate `vacuum` statements to your database, so you're less likely to have this problem in the future.
5. Create a regular backup process, so if you do have this problem (or others) in the future, you have a more confident way forward.

If you can't get a machine with an old enough postgres on it to test the dump files, then you can try loading the dump files into a newer postgres. This *should* work in most cases. It can run into some problems, though. If it works, proceed with steps 2 and on. If it kinda-works, but has some errors, and you're not sure what's up, it might still be worth proceeding with steps 2 and on.

If the dump files *don't* work, you might be hosed. But I'm going to assume they do, because the alternative is sad.

I'm sorry you're in this situation, and I wish you luck.

Comment: *"Since the postgres database is where things like table names, trigger code, etc, are kept, very little is going to work."* No, that's not how PostgreSQL works. Search [initdb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-initdb.html) for this text: "The postgres database is a default database meant for use by users, utilities and third party applications." See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/28261773/562459

Comment: You're absolutely right -- I was conflating the `postgres` database and the catalog. I've updated my answer to reflect that -- the remainder of my answer stands.

Comment: It is perfectly normal that there is no database `postgres`. That was introduced in PostgreSQL 8.1. Also, it is imperative that the database be upgraded to 7.4.30 at the very least. In reality, there cannot be a reason to be on 7.4 unless you don't mind losing your data.